Why my post about comparing date is off-topic?
2 weeks ago, I posted this question : Why is it selecting date from another month that requested one?
Few minutes after, I received an answer that proposed a nice way to fix it.
Last hour, this question have been closed because it seems "off-topic, too localized". (Note: The explaination refer to this meta post that said 'is only applicable to one specific site', but it's not as it's applicable for SO and DBA, but whatever).
About the reason:

"Has typo" : My issue is not a typo, I simply didn't use the right way to compare date
"Basic error" : I didn't get any error
"Not relevant to most of our audience" : It's relevant to all people that compare date, which seems to be a lot of people. Even excluding americain (that could not have this issue), it would be enough

Why is my post closed? What's wrong with it?

Oh, the meta effect is adding downvote to my post, without any explaination as always

Drawing attention to an item often results in more people seeing it that would have otherwise. It seems someone didn't think your question was very good or useful for our site, but then you knew that already, I suppose.

In addition to what Mustaccio said, "closed as too localized" is not intended to be an insult. The theory for the SE sites has always been about documenting the long-tail, but this site isn't about basic programming (which your question seems to be in our estimation). See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for some more information on what we are looking for here, versus over on StackOverflow.
One of the key mandates of all the SE network sites is that they keep things pruned on that long tail to help focus the conversation, to help shape it, and to help reduce the excess noise. While there may be other people with similar questions as yours, it seems pretty easily answered by the MariaDB wiki articles already, and does not seem to require extensive long-tail specific knowledge.
We do feel bad that you had a bad experience, that is not what we want, but there was not likely any malice, just something our community didn't feel belonged.


"Basic error" : I didn't get any error

Though you didn't get an error, you've made a basic error: comparing strings while expecting them to behave as if they were dates.

Yes, but I well compared the same things. I wasn't trying to compare a date to a string, but both date formatted as string in the same way
